# When should I use squared brackets in U-SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Squared brackets (`[]`) are needed in U-SQL when there are spaces in column name. But I also saw this in [U-SQL Tutorial](https://saveenr.gitbooks.io/usql-tutorial/content/extending-usql/deploy-resource.html):

```
System.[IO].File.ReadAllText("helloworld.txt") AS Message
```

I am wondering why brackets are needed in this case, and what are all the cases when `[]` are useful in U-SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `[]` in two scenarios:

1. If you have characters in your name that are not valid .Net/U-SQL identifiers, or
2. the identifiers are all-caps. All-uppercase names longer than 1 character are reserved keywords in U-SQL to allow the language to grow without introducing backwards-incompatibilities.